# Plotting results of numerical differential equation

Tags: plotting, physics

I'm numerically solving the ODE equation $a = -kv$, i.e. $ x'' = -kx'$.

```
sol = NDSolve[{y''[x] + 0.1 * y'[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 10}, y, {x, 0, 100}]
```

I need to do plots of `x` versus time, `v` versus time, and `v` versus `x`.
I figured out how to do the first two plots, but I'm having problems with plotting `v` versus `x` (i.e. `y'` versus `y`)

Comment: You can try using `ParametricPlot` for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
ParametricPlot[{y[t], y'[t]} /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 100},  AspectRatio -> 1/2,
            PlotRange->FullAxesLabel -> {y[t], y'[t]}, LabelStyle -> Directive[20]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]